# After uplift from Spring Boot 2.1.7 to 2.2.0 application does not start due to a FailureAnalyzer

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jdbc, spring-autoconfiguration

I am working on a Spring Boot based project and so far I was using 2.1.7. As I started with HateOas part, I decided to sit on newer HATEOAS 1.0 and so I uplifted my application so Spring Boot 2.2.0.

The only changes I did on my application are:

1. Change the version of Spring Boot in the application's parent pom (Spring Boot is the parent)
2. Adapt to the changes in HATEOAS 1.0 by running the script provided by the hateoas team.

After that all build problems were gone, but then I could no longer have my application started again, since it fails because a certain jdbc class is NOT in the classpath:

*20:22:04.219 DEBUG org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.FailureAnalyzers - FailureAnalyzer org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.HikariDriverConfigurationFailureAnalyzer@2f254559 failed*

```
20:22:04.219 DEBUG org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.FailureAnalyzers - FailureAnalyzer org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.HikariDriverConfigurationFailureAnalyzer@2f254559 failed java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException not present at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:117) ~[?:?] at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:125) ~[?:?]
at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49) ~[?:?]
at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.reifyTypeArguments(Reifier.java:68) ~[?:?]
at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:138) ~[?:?]
at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49) ~[?:?]
at sun.reflect.generics.repository.ClassRepository.computeSuperclass(ClassRepository.java:104) ~[?:?]
at sun.reflect.generics.repository.ClassRepository.getSuperclass(ClassRepository.java:86) ~[?:?]
at java.lang.Class.getGenericSuperclass(Class.java:949) ~[?:?]
at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.getSuperType(ResolvableType.java:467) ~[spring-core-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.as(ResolvableType.java:456) ~[spring-core-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.forClass(ResolvableType.java:1035) ~[spring-core-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.AbstractFailureAnalyzer.getCauseType(AbstractFailureAnalyzer.java:56) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.AbstractFailureAnalyzer.analyze(AbstractFailureAnalyzer.java:33) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.FailureAnalyzers.analyze(FailureAnalyzers.java:110) [spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.FailureAnalyzers.reportException(FailureAnalyzers.java:103) [spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.reportFailure(SpringApplication.java:816) [spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:801) [spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:325) [spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:140) [spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
at com.softuarium.celsvs.webapp.CelsvsWebApp.main(CelsvsWebApp.java:14) [classes/:?]
```

**Environment:**

- Eclipse STS 4 (Version: 4.6.0.RELEASE, Build Id: 202003181317)
- VM-ubuntu18-ES2698:~/celsvs/celsvs-webapp$ java -version
  openjdk version "11.0.6" 2020-01-14
  OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.6+10-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu118.04.1)
  OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.6+10-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu118.04.1, mixed mode)
- VM-ubuntu18-ES2698:~/celsvs/celsvs-webapp$ mvn -version
  Apache Maven 3.6.0
  Maven home: /usr/share/maven
  Java version: 11.0.6, vendor: Ubuntu, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
  Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
  OS name: "linux", version: "5.3.0-46-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"

I have all changes in a specific branch in github. In case someone wants to sniff in, please feel free to clone the repo: https://github.com/asjp1970/celsvs.git and track branch https://github.com/asjp1970/celsvs/tree/celsvs_0-1-0_uplift-spring-2.2.0